# Find hrefs in files using Regex in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have many dita files (XML files) in a folder.

I want to find all occurrences of `href`s for example:

```
href="c_aboutKnowledgeInCoreManage.dita"
href="t_addAnInternalActivityToShift.dita"
```

in the folder using regex and Find in Files filter.

After I find all occurences of `href`s; I want to prefix the term `admin_` in front of `c_aboutKnowledgeInCoreManage.dita`. The output should read `admin_c_aboutKnowledgeInCoreManage.dita`

Can someone help me with the search query?

Comment: The above query worked. Thanks. However, i only want to find hrefs that start with c_<filename>.dita or t_<filename>.dita, for example, href="c_[a-z].dita", or href="t_[a-z].dita"; please help

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to prefix the term `admin_` in front

#### How to delete lines without `.`?

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift></kbd><kbd>F</kbd>
- Set "Find what" to `href="(.*)"`
- Set "Replace with" to `href="admin_\1"`
- Set "Filters" to `*.dita`
- Set "Directory" as appropriate
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace in Files"

  [image]

**Example before**:

```
abcd
href="c_aboutKnowledgeInCoreManage.dita"
defg
href="t_addAnInternalActivityToShift.dita"
hijk
```

**Example after**:

```
abcd
href="admin_c_aboutKnowledgeInCoreManage.dita"
defg
href="admin_t_addAnInternalActivityToShift.dita"
hijk
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: So you only want to change `href`s that end in `.dita`? Please edit the question and clarify.

Comment: The above query worked. Thanks. However, i only want to find hrefs that start with c_<filename>.dita or t_<filename>.dita, for example, href="c_[a-z].dita", or href="t_[a-z].dita"; please help

Comment: @SUHASMURTHY Please spend some time looking at the Further Reading links I provided. I'm not going to modify my answer every time you change your requirements.

Comment: I went through the tutorials and got the solution to my problem. The query (href=.*(dita)) finds only the hrefs (that is, href="t_configuring_an_activity_filter_for_routing.dita) in the files. However, when I run the Replace queries; href="admin_\1", href="admin_{href=.*(dita)}"; href=admin_$+{href=.*(dita)}; I am not getting the desired output. Either the href is being replaced with admin_dita or with admin_href=.*dita. For example, the output shows href="admin_dita" instead of href="admin_t_configuring_an_activity_filter_for_routing.dita". Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @SUHASMURTHY Find what: `href="(.*)(.dita)"` and Replace with: `href="admin_\1\2"`

Comment: @SUHASMURTHY Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).